# И подарит(ь) словарь.....

Tags: грамматика

Это был пост на форуме одном......Вот он......(((Понравился мальчик. Ехали вмести на Житомир, 5 вагон, сидел на 114 мести. Надеюсь он увидит мою запись)))...и к нему прилагался комент....... Ниже два варианта есть.скажите ,как вернее будет...

1).....И подарит словарь.... 
2).....и подарит(ь) словарь.....
 Вот я хочу узнать как верно все же ...

Comment: @Dron, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

-(((Понравился мальчик. Ехали вмести на Житомир, 5 вагон, сидел на 114 мести. Надеюсь, он увидит мою запись)))

-И подарит словарь...(увидит и что сделает?)

(Правильный комментарий, я поддерживаю)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения автора поста, который сидел "на 114 мести", конечно, правильно "и подарить словарь".

Comment: Не нападайте на человека :-)

Уровень знания языка (в том числе русского языка) может быть очень разный!

В вопросе упоминался Житомир. Это Украина. Там русский язык теперь в школах или совсем не изучают или очень мало изучают. Так что дети могут хорошо знать разговорную русскую речь от родителей или знакомых и при этом плохо писать по-русски. Хочешь учиться писать по-русски? Учись сам!

Так что -- зашёл человек на форум "Русский язык", интересуется как правильно написать -- и молодец!

Comment: Ни на кого я не нападаю. Как я поняла, варианты "и подарит / и подарить" приводились в комментах под постом, который прочитал автор вопроса. В комментах кто-то явно пошутил. Я всего лишь объяснила смысл шутки. Неужели можно было понять как-то иначе? Вы меня удивили.